# pytorch cnn Test result is sticked

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

**TRAINING CODE**

```
if os.path.isfile(PATH):
      print("checkpoint training '{}' ...".format(PATH))
      checkpoint = torch.load(PATH)
      start_epoch = checkpoint['epoch']
      start_i = checkpoint['i']
      net.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])
      print("=> loaded checkpoint '{}' (trained for {} epochs, {} i)".format(PATH, checkpoint['epoch'],
                                                                           checkpoint['i']))
    else:
        print('new training')

for epoch in range(num_epochs):  # loop over the dataset multiple times
    running_loss = 0.0
    for i in range(len(train_folder_list2)):
        # get the inputs; data is a list of [inputs, labels]
        # net.train()
        inputs, labels = train_input[i], train_list[i]
        inputs = torch.as_tensor(inputs).cuda()
        inputs = inputs.transpose(1, 3)
        labels = torch.as_tensor(labels).cuda()
        # forward + backward + optimize
        outputs = net(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

        # zero the parameter gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        running_loss += loss.item()
        if i % 100 == 1:
            save_checkpoint({
               'epoch': start_epoch + epoch + 1,
               'i': start_i + i + 1,
               'state_dict': net.state_dict(),
        })
```

**TEST CODE**

```
PATH = './checkpoint.pth'
model = Net().cuda()
if os.path.isfile(PATH):
    print('checkpoint check!')
    checkpoint = torch.load(PATH)
    model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])
    model.eval()

for k in range(len(train_folder_list2)):
    inputs = train_input[k]
    inputs = torch.as_tensor(inputs).cuda()
    inputs = inputs.transpose(1, 3)
    outputs = model(inputs)
    result = outputs.cpu().detach().numpy()
```

This is the code to find the edges of the image.

If I run the training code, train it, and test it with the test code, it doesn't seem to find any edges in the image. The edges are on the same side, whatever image i put.

**ADD
**CNN CODE**
In addition, we added cnn code to give you information. Data input was put in the list separately from the image and label.

```
class Net(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super(Net, self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
    self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(293904, 120)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
    self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 18)

def forward(self, x):
    x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
    x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
    x = x.view(-1, 293904)
    x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
    x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
    x = self.fc3(x)
    x = x.view(18)

    return x
```

Comment: Please notice that the `cnn` tag refers to something completely different than CNNs and it should not be used here - tag with `conv-neural-network` instead (edited).

Comment: This is not enough information. Is this a segmentation task? What does your model look like?

Comment: Theodor Peifer : I added a model. And all the code is all in one file.